# Building spring-ide-3.6.3.RELEASE error

Tags: spring-tool-suite

There is error while building spring-ide-3.6.3.RELEASE.
The error message is:

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.springframework.ide.eclipse:org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core:3.6.3-SNAPSHOT @ /opt/sources/spring-ide-3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core/pom.xml
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=cocoa, osgi.os=macosx, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier requires 'package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0)' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.v_OTDT_r220_201306071800 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.1.v_OTDT_r221_201309101918 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.2.v_OTDT_r222_201402180730 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.asm [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.config [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.classreading [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.filter [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.configurator 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to bundle org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.v_OTDT_r220_201306071800 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.1.v_OTDT_r221_201309101918 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.2.v_OTDT_r222_201402180730 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.asm [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.config [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.classreading [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.filter [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.configurator 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to bundle org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.v_OTDT_r220_201306071800 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.1.v_OTDT_r221_201309101918 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.2.v_OTDT_r222_201402180730 to org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.asm [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.config [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.context.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.annotation [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.io.support [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.classreading [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.core.type.filter [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core 3.6.3.qualifier to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to package org.springframework.util [4.0.0,4.1.0).; Unable to satisfy dependency from org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.configurator 3.6.4.201412120019-CI-B3 to bundle org.springframework.core [4.0.0,4.1.0).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
    ...
```

Comment: The update site for the Eclipse integration commons components is there and accessible. Maybe a temporary network issue? Or a proxy in between? Are you running the Maven/Tycho build for STS or is this showing up in the IDE when checking for updates?

Comment: I rebuild and there is other error.

Comment: glad to hear that and thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought it is working now for you. Sorry for my misunderstanding. What other error is showing up?

Comment: Thx for reply. The error message updated in the question, and there is no other error message else , and build with debug mode of maven.@MartinLippert

Comment: The error looks like you are trying to build a 3.6.3 version of the Spring IDE projects against a nightly build repo of dependent components. What do you exactly want to build? The 3.6.3.RELEASE version of Spring IDE components? If so, there are additional information for the tycho build necessary so that the build consumes dependent components from their release repository as well (instead of their nightly repo). So what exactly are you trying to do and what is the exact command line you are using?

Comment: To build a release vesion of Spring IDE, you can't just go to the release tag and run the plain snapshot build.  For example, the release build of Spring IDE is configured like this:

clean deploy -Pe37 -Ddist.type=release -Dp2.qualifier=RELEASE -Ddist.pathpostfix=3.6.3.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks very much. Build successful. But there is another question that how to setup a spring ide developing environment. I run the command: mvn eclipse:eclipse, and it's successful, and I import the projects into eclipse.But there are many errors. @MartinLippert

Comment: I could develop in a eclipse with spring-ide plugins or in the STS. But that means developing depend on the version of ide.

Comment: You don't need to run mvn eclipse:eclipse, the feature and plugin projects from the GitHub projects are ready-to-import Eclipse projects already. You might end up with compile errors, but that is very likely related to the target environment that you have defined for plugin development in Eclipse or STS, since Spring IDE plugins depend on Eclipse plugins. But that is a bit too much for this comment, I would recommend to open up a new thread for this.